# Is there a trick to dodging?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

In the tutorial, they said "hold L1 to dodge attacks" *(I am using control-layout B)*.  They make it sound like you're basically invincible while holding the button.  However in actual battles I've noticed that while holding L1, I still get hit *a lot*.  Why?

- Does holding the button stop dodging after a certain amount of time?
- Do I need to press the button within a certain amount of time prior to the attack?
- Do I need to be facing and/or locked-onto the enemy?
- Are some attacks just not dodgeable? *(is there any way to tell?)*
- Can I not dodge for a certain amount of time after attacking?
- Is there any way to tell if my dodge is 'active'?  (in the HUD, or my character's posture, etc)
- Is there a cooldown between dodges?

Comment: For other people having trouble with dodging or the controls in general: There is a lot of HOLDING in this game. Don't mash the buttons. Hold it down for a bit. This includes attacking.

Answer (score 5):

Okay going through the list here.

- No. Dodging will not stop if you keep holding the button.
- No. You can hold down the button to keep in dodge mode.
- No. You do not need to be locked on or facing the enemy to dodge.
- From what I can tell there aren't any undodgeable attacks (unsure on this fact)
- Depending on your weapon you may not be able to dodge for a short bit after attack. Larger weapons are prone to this such as the great swords.
- From what I have seen you can tell you are in dodge mode when your character walks around slower and seems to hunch over a little bit like if he was holding a shield.

I am pretty sure your problem is with larger groups of enemies, or enemies with large attack arcs. From my observation, while you are in dodge mode, you are not immune to being attacked. If enemies gang up on you while you are dodging other attacks you **can still be hit.** Same goes with enemies with larger attack arcs, you may get off the dodge, but an arc of an attack can still hit you. Your best bet for these situations is to simply dodge roll out of the area and not hold your dodge button.

Comment: Doesn't dodging also use mana? When you run out, you'll be in a sort of recovery mode?

Comment: Not from what I have seen, the largest use of mana is using the warp strikes. I have had situations where I have been on constant dodge mode and haven't gone into stasis. Once I get home I'll try it out and see I didn't notice mana change when I played though.

Comment: To add a bit to my answer, I did test last night and dodging **does not use mana** so feel free to just hold the button.

Comment: I'm not sure what you tested, but dodging definitely does use mana, and is even mentioned, multiple times, during the tutorial for dodging.  Holding the button actually uses mana, which is why it's better to time your dodges.  Rolling does not use mana, but dodging/phasing does.

Comment: Huh it does, I could have sworn that I wasn't burning MP on dodging.

Comment: There are nodes in the ascension tree that let you reduce the amount of mana spent for phasing and even recover mana when phasing at the last moment.

Answer (score -1):

I think dodges are more successful if there is only one enemy attacking you at once and if you dodge just before the attack